# Authenticating users of an API using a 3rd-party Oauth provider

Tags: javascript, api, rest, oauth

I'm transitioning a server-side web app to a single-page JavaScript app using a RESTful API. Currently. users can authenticate using Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc. or via email and password. How do I allow the same forms of authentication running over a RESTful API? I'm guessing it looks something like this:

1. Authenticate with the provider on the client side.
2. Take something from the Oauth response and pass it to an API on my server in exchange for an access token.
3. Use token-based auth for subsequent API calls.

Am I on the right track? If so:

1. Is there a JS library that handles multiple providers, or will each one require including something like Facebook's JS SDK?
2. What should my API look like that generates the token? In particular, what do I need from the Oauth provider and how do I verify it on the server?

Comment: Often have I found "off-topic" questions that perfectly fits my needs. Looking at the upvotes, it's a question many people ask themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be easier for you to handle the authentication process against the identity providers on the server side and not on the client side. 
So your REST server should support it's own authentication method (that could be also OAuth based), and transfer this to the third party provider. So a flow will look something like this:

1. Initiate a login process from the client (JS) - call your REST auth endpoint, specifying the network you want to login to (e.g. myserver.com/login?provider=facebook).
2. Handle the login process on the server side - redirect to the provider login endpoint, receive the login callback, process the response (get the facebook session token etc.).
3. Issue your own user session (or token if you're doing OAuth), and respond back to your JS client.

There are a couple of social login libraries that can help you, check out http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ for PHP or http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/ for Java.

There are also a couple of commercial solutions that can make your life a lot easier (I'm working for [Gigya](http://gigya.com) so I'm biased), but that's only if you have a budget.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense from a technical perspective. I was thinking from a UX-angle, hoping there was some way to stay within my single-page-app without redirecting. It looks like that's possible for Facebook using their JS SDK, but probably not more generally.

Comment: You can avoid redirecting from your page by opening a popup. You don't have to redirect to your login REST endpoint from the single page, you can open a popup to that endpoint, and the redirection to the IDP (like facebook) will be done in that popup window. At the end of the login process you have to signal from the popup to the JS on your main page with the login response and session.

Comment: Perfect! As I've only worked within a single window I hadn't thought of communicating between a popup and the page.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend generating an API access keys or using a separate OAuth flow specifically for your API. Conceptually you'll want to separate the act of creating an account with your service, and connecting remote accounts. You could probably pull off what you're describing, but it will be confusing.

For making OAuth easier in the client, check out [oauth.io](http://oauth.io)